# Cosmology: Partical horizons and structure formation

Tags: cosmology, structure-formation

In the concept of 'particle horizons' and structure formation. How would I show that before the matter-radiation equality, the *proper* particle horizon during this era evolves as Dh=2ct, where t is cosmic time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particle horizon is just the distance moved by a light ray in time $t$. To calculate this we start with the FLRW metric. We'll consider only radial motion so $d\theta = d\phi = 0$ and the metric simplifies to:

$$ ds^ = -c^2dt^2 + a^2(t)dr^2 \tag{1} $$

For a light ray $ds = 0$ and substituting this in equation (1) and rearranging we get:

$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = \frac{c}{a(t)} $$

The distance moved is then calculated by integrating:

$$ r(t) = c \int_0^t \frac{dt'}{a(t')} $$

But note that this is the distance in comovong coordinates, so to get the distance in our coordinates we have to multiply by the scale factor. So our final equation is:

$$ R(t) = c a(t) \int_0^t \frac{dt'}{a(t')} \tag{2} $$

where $R$ is now our particle horizon.

During the radiation dominated era the scale factor is proportional to the square root of time, so we write:

$$ a(t) = kt^{1/2} $$

for some constant $k$. Substituting this into equation (2) we get:

$$\begin{align}
 R(t) &= ckt^{1/2} \int_0^t \frac{dt'}{kt'^{1/2}} \\
      &= c t^{1/2} \left[ 2t'^{1/2} \right]_0^t \\
      &= 2ct
\end{align}$$

Comment: @DonH95: Hi Don. If you're happy that this answers your question please click the tick symbol to accept the answer.

Comment: Done, many thanks. I have a few more questions of this nature. Would it be best to just post here or would a more direct method be ok also?

Comment: @DonH95: feel free to post here.

Comment: Here's the link http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/219989/observed-flux-from-distant-galaxies